# What are all the saiyans transformations branches in Dragon Ball series?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Saiyans can turn into Super Saiyan using their proper Ki, but they can also goes to Super Saiyan God using divine ki. Then, Broly & Kale have the Berserker form, etc.

What are all the main branches of transformations in *Dragon Ball* series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting a new answer because I got your question wrong. If I understand correctly, this is what you are asking.

- Regular super saiyan transformation (SSJ1, SSJ2, USSJ, SSJ3, etc.)
- Super Saiyan god, Saiyan beyond god (saiyan using god ki)
- Super Saiyan Blue, Mastered Super Saiyan Blue, Super Saiyan Evolution (saiyan using god ki and turning into super saiyan)
- Legendary Super Saiyan, Super Saiyan Berserker, Legendary Super Saiyan 2, etc. (only certain types of special saiyans can achieve it)
- Super Saiyan Rage (unknown what it takes to get it)
- Super Saiyan Rose (god in the body of a super saiyan)
- Ultra Instinct Omen, Mastered Ultra Instinct (assuming that aside of a skill it's a saiyan transformation in the way Goku gets it, with that aura and hair and eyes etc achievable by anyone in theory)
- Oozaru, Golden Oozaru (non canon) (saiyan with tale who sees the moon)
- Super Saiyan 4 (non canon, it requires the saiyan to have a tale)

Comment: Also, there is a way to transform to a ssj4 without a tail, using specials machines that emit blutz waves. Such a machine was constructed by Bulma that allowed baby and Vegeta to transform: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Blutz_Wave_Generator

Comment: what about SSB Vegito and SSJ Vegito?